# Why the CD access in Ubuntu Server is different than expected according with FHS?

Tags: server, mount, filesystem, automount, fhs

About to get access to a CD through the terminal - with *Virtual Box* working with Ubuntu **Desktop** and **Server**, when the *Guest Additions .iso* file is inserted through:

- `Devices` -> `Insert Guest Additions CD image`

For the **Desktop** environment its access is through `/media/<username>/VBox_GAs_#.#.#` and for the **Server** environment its access is through `/dev/cdrom`, it to be mount it with the `sudo mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom` command.

Observe the difference between `/media` and `/dev`

**Question**

- Why the CD access in Ubuntu **Server** is different than expected according with **FHS**?

I assumed it should be `/media` too - it taking in consideration again the `FHS` - it according with:

- [3.11. /media : Mount point for removable media](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s11.html)

**Note** this situation happens for the 18.04LTS and 20.04LTS

Comment: Uh, **you** mounted it at `/cdrom`. Nobody stopped you from mounting it at `/media` or wherever. Even on Ubuntu Desktop, if you check the **device** that's mounted at `/media/<username>/VBox_GAs_#.#.#`, it will be `/dev/cdrom*`

Comment: For the Desktop environment, when I insert the `.iso` file - automatically the path is generated to that location. Same as for the Server Environment - I mean, I must use `/dev/cdrom` to mount - well - is `/cdrom` correct? I used the `sudo mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom` command according with a tutorial to install the VB Guest Additions - for Desktop and Server environments

Comment: Did you use the `/dev/cdrom` path to mount in the desktop environment?

Comment: When `Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image` is accomplished in the **Desktop** Environment appears a CD icon in the Desktop, then I open a new terminal, the location of the `Guest Addition` content - of the CD - is `/media/<username>/VBox_GAs_#.#.#` - important to notice that I did **not** mount nothing manually

Comment: Exactly, you mounted nothing manually. And the content of the CD is at `/media/<username>/VBox_GAs_#.#.#`. And when you mount the CD manually at `/cdrom`, the content is at `/cdrom`. Yet, you are for some reason comparing`/media/<username>/VBox_GAs_#.#.#`  with `/dev/cdrom`. Why? How are those two equivalent?

Comment: Oh, now I see the difference. There is no difference about the source for the mount process, being automatic or not - it uses `/dev/cdrom*` like you said in your first comment - of course the difference is about the target of the mount process, in Desktop was automatic to `/media`. And according with the tutorial in the server environment was manually to `/cdrom`

Comment: @muru consider to put your comment how an answer about the: `if you check the device` .... `/dev/cdrom*` situation. With an extra expansion of explanation/content. It to mark it how solved. Thank You